# jquery if hours and minutes <>

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Please, How can I set IF when time is < 21:30 ??

```
var dt = new Date();
if ((dt.getHours() <= 21) && (dt.getMinutes() <= 30)) { alert("check"); }
```

This not working when time is example 20:45

Comment: @pavel It dont work, look at https://jsfiddle.net/p04rjwsg/ For `20:45` - `dt.getHours() <= 21` will be true but `dt.getMinutes() <= 30` will be false

Comment: What does Jquery have to do with this? This is vanilla javascript

Comment: @pavel if dt is equal to 20:45 he want the alert to fire. but it will of course not

Comment: I misread the question, sure, it doesn't work... sorry.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen can only image your downvote was due to harcoded comparison date?

Comment: @freedomn-m true, i've also noticed that when I deleted the question. I know it was my mistake but hate when someone don't explain why they downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check two different things.

1. if hours <= 20, than everything is true.
2. if hours == 21, than check minutes.

```js
var dt = new Date('2021/03/18 20:45:00');
if (dt.getHours() <= 20 || (dt.getHours() == 21 && dt.getMinutes() <= 30)) { 
    alert("check"); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like a serial downvoter - maybe someone doesn't like the question so they're downvoting viable answers.

Comment: @freedomn-m: maybe... I don't play for rep, if anybody wants to downvote, he can :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could always take the time and convert it to minutes in the day - 1440 (60*24) so 21:30 becomes 21 * 60 + 30 = 1,290.

We can calculate the current minute value by taking the current date time `Date.now()` (milliseconds since 1/1/1970) mod 86,400,000 (milliseconds in a day) * further divide this by 60,000 (milliseconds in a minute).

```
(Date.now() % 86_400_000) / (60_000)
```

It is then trivial to compare these two values

```js
const nineFortyFivePM = 21 * 60 + 30;
const currentMinutes = (Date.now() % 86_400_000) / (60_000);

console.log(`21:45 = ${nineFortyFivePM}`);
console.log(`currentMinutes = ${currentMinutes}`);
if (currentMinutes < nineFortyFivePM)
  alert('check');
```